# How to configure outbound channel adapter with synchronization factory in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

What would be the equivalent of the following outbound channel adapter configuration in spring boot? Assuming the `messageChannel`, `taskExecutor`, and `synchronizationFactory` are defined.

```
    <int:outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundChannelAdapter" channel="messageChannel" ref="handler" method="handle">
        <int:poller task-executor="taskExecutor" fixed-delay="500" receive-timeout="500" max-messages-per-poll="10">
            <int:transactional synchronization-factory="synchronizationFactory" isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
        </int:poller>
    </int:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

The `@ServiceActivator` with the `@Poller` annotation doesn't seem to have an option for transaction synchronization factory.
The `PollerMetadata` has an option for it but I'm not sure how to connect that instance to the `@ServiceActivator`.

The synchronization factory is needed in this case because it's a DB-based channel with multiple threads reading from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "messageChannel", poller = @Poller("myPollerMetadata"))
public void handle(Message<?> message) { // Or what is your service method signature
    ...
}

@Bean
PollerMetadata myPollerMetadata(Executor taskExecutor, TransactionSynchronizationFactory synchronizationFactory) {

    PollerMetadata poller = new PollerMetadata();
    poller.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(synchronizationFactory);
    poller.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(10);
    poller.setReceiveTimeout(500);
    poller.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    poller.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(500));
    return poller;
}
```

You may also consider to start learning Spring Integration Java DSL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl. The same config would look like this:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow myHandlerFlow(Executor taskExecutor, TransactionSynchronizationFactory synchronizationFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("messageChannel")
              .handle(handler, "handle", 
                            c -> c.poller(p -> p
                                     .fixedDelay(500)
                                     .transactionSynchronizationFactory(synchronizationFactory)
                                     .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                                     .receiveTimeout(500)
                                     .maxMessagesPerPoll(10)))
              .get();
}
```

Comment: That works. Thank you for your help Artem. And for the useful tip. That looks like a much easier way to configure it. Appreciate your time.